# How can I solve this Flutter SDK version error?

Tags: android, flutter, macos, sdk, version

The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.

Because provider 5.0.0 requires Flutter SDK version >=1.16.0 and no versions of provider match >5.0.0 <6.0.0, provider ^5.0.0 is forbidden.

So, because *flutter_app* depends on provider ^5.0.0, version solving failed.

Pub get failed (1; So, because *flutter_app* depends on provider ^5.0.0, version solving failed.)

That's the error I’m getting when trying to run 'flutter pub get' in Android Studio.

Below is the *pubspec.yaml* file:

Please note, I’m running Android Studio on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS).

```
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  mqtt_client: ^7.2.1




  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  provider: ^5.0.0



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/outline_settings_white_18.png


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to the terminal and upgrade the SDK version by the

```
flutter upgrade
```

Command. This command is for both Mac and Windows.

If it shows an error, run

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Flutter probably had a problem while installing.

You can use Git commands to fix it.

Run these commands on your Flutter SDK, not on your project files.

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

You can check [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted).

Comment: Unfortunately the error still persists.
Do i have to run it inside flutter bin folder?

Comment: @AKSHAYSETHIA Nope, you should run it inside the flutter folder. (the file comes before bin file) If it doesn't works, you may try to install new flutter in different location. https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install

Comment: Thanks,
By any chance is it due to the "publisher" dependency?

Comment: I don't see any publisher dependency in your project. I think you meant provider. If it is what you think, you can use this command to solve. `provider: any`

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/akshaysethia/Flutter/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

That error in pub get is solved but this error pops up when running the code.

*Posting additional error in next comment

Comment: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
    return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This is the main error it seems

Comment: This bring too much problem with it self, try this: `provider: ^6.0.2`

Comment: The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.

Because flutter_app depends on provider >=4.0.0-dev which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.12.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because flutter_app depends on provider >=4.0.0-dev which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.12.1, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

Back to original error

Comment: Again as I said, this problem happens because there is problem with your flutter installation. Did you tried to install it to somewhere else? Please install through official website.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error message

```
[project] flutter pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.
```

Run this command in Git Bash

```
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Users/YourUser/AppData/Local/Android/flutter
```

or

```
git config --global --add safe.directory "Path to flutter directory"
```

Then to check

```
flutter upgrade  or flutter doctor -v
```